# Unprotected redirect not cured by only_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, brakeman

I have a Rails 4 application, and when I run Brakeman, it (rightly) identifies an unprotected redirect in my create action.  However, adding only_path: true (as in the [Brakeman Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/358-brakeman)) does not cure the warning:

```
  def create
    refer_url = params[:referrer]
    @portfolio = current_user.portfolios.build(portfolio_params)
    if @portfolio.save
      redirect_to refer_url, notice: "Portfolio was successfully created.", only_path: true
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Results in:

```
+SECURITY WARNINGS+

+------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
| Confidence | Class                 | Method  | Warning Type | Message                                                                                                               >>
+------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
| High       | PortfoliosController  | create  | Redirect     | Possible unprotected redirect near line 14: redirect_to(+params[:referrer]+, :notice => "Portfolio was successfully cr>>
+------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
```

Why might this be?  What risk is Brakeman still identifying?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The RailsCast is incorrect, unfortunately. `:only_path => true` must be part of the *first* argument.

Is `params[:referrer]` supposed to be a path in your application?

If so, this would be my recommendation:

```
begin
  refer_url = URI.parse(params[:referrer]).path
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  refer_url = "some_default"
end
```

Or you could check that `params[:referrer]` is always a path, validate it some other way, or just don't allow arbitrary redirects even within your application. Sadly, Rails does not give easy options for safe redirects.

Comment: This indeed satisfies Brakeman and is very sensible.  Thank you!

Comment: I think it might be better not to use exceptions for control flow:

```if params[:referrer] =~ URI::regexp
      refer_url = URI.parse(params[:referrer]).path
    else
      refer_url = "some_default"
    end```